# How do I run a binary linked against a shared library without using LD_LIBRARY_PATH or rpath?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, file-not-found

This has been bugging me for a while. I tried linking a shared object to an executable in one of my projects (structured like this):

```
.
├── lib.c
├── lib.h
├── main.c
└── Makefile
```

...using this Makefile:

```
CC != if command -v clang; then continue; elif command -v gcc; then continue; else echo c99; fi

.PHONY: build

build: main
    ./main

lib.so: lib.c
    $(CC)  -shared -fPIC -o lib.so lib.c

main: main.c lib.so
    $(info Building executable: "main")
    $(CC) -o main main.c lib.so
```

...but then I got this error: `./main: error while loading shared libraries: lib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I did find some existing solutions, involving the use of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable or the `-Wl,-rpath=path/to/dir` compile flag, but let's just say that I want another way of fixing this problem.

I know, just hear me out. I've been able to successfully run binaries linked to a shared object in a hierarchical structure, like so:

```
.
├── bin/
│   └── main
├── lib/
│   └── lib.so
├── src/
│   ├── lib.c
│   ├── lib.h
│   └── main.c
└── Makefile
```

...and I didn't need to use either method. I also used `ldd` on the binary in the above example:

```
$ ldd bin/main
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffec55e7000)
    lib/lib.so (0x00007f3198a7f000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3198876000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3198a8b000)
```

In comparison to the troublesome binary:

```
$ ldd main
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc2de5f000)
    lib.so => not found
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007880524c3000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007880526d3000)
```

While I might be making an assumption here, I will not pretend that I haven't found an answer to this question yet. I will be posting my own solution not long after I have posted this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...but then I got this error: `./main: error while loading shared libraries: lib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

1. You should *not* name your library `lib.so`. Name it something like `libfoo.so` (where `foo` represents the functionality that the library provides.
2. You should *not* link your main executable using the path to `libfoo.so`.
   Instead, do this: `$(CC) -o main main.c -L. -lfoo`.
3. In order to make your binary find `libfoo.so` at runtime, you need to encode into the binary instructions for the dynamic loader telling it where to look.

There are several common approaches for (3):

- Use system library directories. For this you copy `libfoo.so` into e.g. `/usr/local/lib`
- Use a fixed directory, e.g. current location. For this, add `-Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)` to the link line. Note that you'll need to escape `$` when adding this command to the `Makefile`.
  This approach has a disadvantage: if you rename your directory, the binary will stop working.
- Use directory *relative* to where the binary itself was found. For this, add `-Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'`. This approach allows you to freely copy `{main,libfoo.so}` to a different directory and remove the original. The binary will continue to work so long as both `main` and `libfoo.so` are in present the same directory.
- Use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. This has an advantage of being easy to update if/when you moved the project directory, but a disadvantage in that you have to maintain that variable, and the binary will or will not work depending on the environment it runs in.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This is not actually the correct answer, since the executable will only work in one directory, as pointed out by the first comment below.

---

I just needed to put `./` before the shared object file name in the compile options to get it to link the shared object successfully in the same  directory. That's literally it. Now the Makefile looks like this:

```
CC != if command -v clang; then continue; elif command -v gcc; then continue; else echo c99; fi

.PHONY: build

build: main
    ./main

lib.so: lib.c
    $(CC) -shared -fPIC -o lib.so lib.c

main: main.c lib.so
    $(info Building executable: "main")
    $(CC) -o main main.c ./lib.so
# The little './' determines whether the executable would successfully link to lib.so or not

clean:
    rm main lib.so
```

And using `ldd` on the now-working executable:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd92ba4000)
    ./lib.so (0x000077142594c000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x0000771425743000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000771425958000)
```

That aside, I also discovered that shared object files can indeed be linked in any directory that is not the working directory, which explains how my previous work with a shared library didn't cause any problems so far.

Comment: "I just needed to put ./ before the shared object file name ..." -- this binary will _only_ run when you are in this particular directory, which is usually undesirable.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice this. I shall reflect my changes in this answer.